# Remove duplicates based on timestamp order

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Timestamp=as.POSIXct(strptime(c('2018-01-08 13:26:53', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 13:33:33', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 13:45:12', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 14:26:22', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 14:28:34', 
                                                 '2018-01-08 14:31:32',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:11:14',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:13:16',
                                                 '2018-01-08 15:25:19'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")),
                 Text=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'))
```

Output:

```
            Timestamp Text
1 2018-01-08 13:26:53    A
2 2018-01-08 13:33:33    A
3 2018-01-08 13:45:12    A
4 2018-01-08 14:26:22    B
5 2018-01-08 14:28:34    C
6 2018-01-08 14:31:32    C
7 2018-01-08 15:11:14    A
8 2018-01-08 15:13:16    A
9 2018-01-08 15:25:19    B
```

I want to remove only duplicates which repeat themself in order and only keep the latest rows. So I want a dataframe like this:

```
            Timestamp Text
1 2018-01-08 13:45:12    A
2 2018-01-08 14:26:22    B
3 2018-01-08 14:31:32    C
4 2018-01-08 15:13:16    A
5 2018-01-08 15:25:19    B
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create groups and select only `max` `Timestamp` from each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(group = rleid(Text)) %>%
  slice(which.max(Timestamp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

# Timestamp           Text 
#  <dttm>              <fct>
#1 2018-01-08 13:45:12 A    
#2 2018-01-08 14:26:22 B    
#3 2018-01-08 14:31:32 C    
#4 2018-01-08 15:13:16 A    
#5 2018-01-08 15:25:19 B
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completness: using `rle` to find repeated value:

```
df <- data.table(df)
  a <- rle(df$Text)
  df[, groups :=  rep(seq(1, length(a$lengths)), a$lengths)]
  df
  df[, .SD[.N, ], by = groups]

   groups           Timestamp Text
1:      1 2018-01-08 13:45:12    A
2:      2 2018-01-08 14:26:22    B
3:      3 2018-01-08 14:31:32    C
4:      4 2018-01-08 15:13:16    A
5:      5 2018-01-08 15:25:19    B
```

**EDIT**
And benchmark (with larger set)

```
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[, lapply(.SD, sample, size = 10000, replace = TRUE), .SDcols = colnames(df)]

aa <- function(){
  a <- rle(df$Text)
  df[, groups :=  rep(seq(1, length(a$lengths)), a$lengths)]
  df[, .SD[.N, ], by = groups]
}

aa2 <- function(){
  df[, group := rleid(Text)]
  df[, .SD[.N, ], by = group]
}

bb <- function(){
  df %>%
    group_by(group = rleid(Text)) %>%
    slice(which.max(Timestamp)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-group)
}

cc <- function(){
  df %>%
    mutate(Group = cumsum(c(FALSE, df$Text[-1] != df$Text[-n()]))) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    filter(row_number() == n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-Group)
}



> microbenchmark(aa(), aa2(), bb(), cc(), times = 5)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  aa() 1212.6609 1252.2010 1267.8729 1279.0700 1282.9894 1312.4432     5   c
 aa2() 1213.9839 1271.1910 1275.3573 1283.8008 1299.9422 1307.8685     5   c
  bb()  112.8352  116.5473  152.9838  142.4634  160.9753  232.0976     5 a  
  cc()  306.1699  306.4497  316.5756  315.7423  326.8091  327.7069     5  b
```

Comment: you need to apply benchmark on a bigger dataset. Applying benchmark on dataframe with 9 rows would not give you any meaningful insights.

Comment: @RonakShah fair point, also now I am guessing `rleid` will most likley be faster than `rle` in larger sets.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Timestamp), .SD[!duplicated(rleid(Text), fromLast = TRUE)]]

             Timestamp Text
1: 2018-01-08 13:45:12    A
2: 2018-01-08 14:26:22    B
3: 2018-01-08 14:31:32    C
4: 2018-01-08 15:13:16    A
5: 2018-01-08 15:25:19    B
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses package `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Group = cumsum(c(FALSE, df$Text[-1] != df$Text[-n()]))) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group)
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Timestamp           Text 
#  <dttm>              <fct>
#1 2018-01-08 13:45:12 A    
#2 2018-01-08 14:26:22 B    
#3 2018-01-08 14:31:32 C    
#4 2018-01-08 15:13:16 A    
#5 2018-01-08 15:25:19 B
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier using the `hutils::duplicated_rows` function.

```r
library(data.table)
library(hutils)
df <- data.frame(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(strptime(x = c('2018-01-08 13:26:53', 
                                                       '2018-01-08 13:33:33', 
                                                       '2018-01-08 13:45:12', 
                                                       '2018-01-08 14:26:22', 
                                                       '2018-01-08 14:28:34', 
                                                       '2018-01-08 14:31:32',
                                                       '2018-01-08 15:11:14',
                                                       '2018-01-08 15:13:16',
                                                       '2018-01-08 15:25:19'),
                                                 format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")),
                 Text = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'))
duplicated_rows(DT = as.data.table(x = df),
                by = "Text")
#>              Timestamp Text
#> 1: 2018-01-08 13:26:53    A
#> 2: 2018-01-08 13:33:33    A
#> 3: 2018-01-08 13:45:12    A
#> 4: 2018-01-08 15:11:14    A
#> 5: 2018-01-08 15:13:16    A
#> 6: 2018-01-08 14:26:22    B
#> 7: 2018-01-08 15:25:19    B
#> 8: 2018-01-08 14:28:34    C
#> 9: 2018-01-08 14:31:32    C
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>